# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot run Liquibase, liquibase.datasource is not set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, liquibase

After configuring liquibase in my pom.xml. I have also added these files in my resources folder, changelog.xml and this is the content

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog'
      xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
      xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd'>
      <changeSet id="001" author="Dev">
        <sql>
          ALTER TABLE book ADD COLUMN address VARCHAR(1024);
        </sql>
      </changeSet>
    </databaseChangeLog>
```

I have also added this file liquibase.properties in my resources folder and this is the content

```
contexts: ${liquibase.contexts} 
changeLogFile: src/main/resources/changelog.xml 
driver: ${jdbc.driverClassName} 
url: ${jdbc.url} 
username: ${jdbc.username} 
verbose: true 
dropFirst: false
```

I have also configured my pom.xml like this

```
<plugin>
           <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
           <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.5</version>
           <configuration>                  
              <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
           </configuration>                
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>process-resources</phase>                                                                  
               <goals>
                 <goal>update</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>

        </plugin>
```

When I launch my project I get this error from tomcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot run Liquibase, liquibase.datasource is not set
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: did you enable resource filtering (with maven) ?

Comment: Please can you show me

Comment: I started a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115523/liquibase). Maybe I can give you some hints...

Answer (score 0):

If you use placeholders in your liquibase.properties file, you must also enable resource filtering with the following element in your pom.xml :

```
<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

(if you don't do that : liquibase.properties will remains with stuff like

```
url: ${jdbc.url}
```

and of course, this is not a valid url.)

Comment: Still thesame issue Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot run Liquibase, liquibase.datasource is not set

Comment: I did a maven build and after that I am having this error in my changelog.xml >>>>>  cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'databaseChangeLog'.

Comment: be sure that your execution directory is your project root.

Comment: I am executing the project like this>>>> Right click on the project >>>>> select Run as >>>>>> then run on server.

Comment: src/main/resources don't exists "on server". the changelog file is at root of classpath.

Comment: So where do I add the changelog.xml file

Comment: In the webapp folder?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot run Liquibase, liquibase.datasource is not set

Comment: How can I find liquibase.datasource

Comment: From the liquibase documentation, i did not see any file like liquibase.datasource

Comment: Question is : do you really plan to execute liquibase with maven on your server ? It sounds a bit strange : maven is a build tool and usually is not use "on server"

Comment: Okay! Are you trying to mean that liquibase is not used on server?

Comment: So I should execute liquibase from command prompt of my maven project?

Comment: I mean that maven should probably not be used on production server, liquibase can be use on production server, but then shouldn't be triggered by maven.

Comment: IMHO a good example of how a question can be hard to read/follow when you don't stick to the concept of one problem = one question. 
@Blaze: I seems to me you should try to read more about the whole process that you are trying to do. It will be tough to get you going by hopping from error to error. Start with liquibase by itself. No Maven and no maybe no eclipse. Just run it from command line. Once you get that done try to setup maven with liquibase (maybe still without eclipse). Once that works, put everything into eclipse. Just a suggestion...